# Cloud service to store email activity and to pull reports

Tags: email, reporting, cloud, integration, storage

What is a good way to store and run some reports on email analytics? Imagine this is a pretty high volume of emails sent, open, click stats broken down to email categories. This info has to be stored at some DB and we need to be able to slice the data in different ways to extract some valuable business information.

One way to do this would be in-house, build a new database and log and track every action. And later on built reports on top of it.

However, this is a lot of work and I was wondering if there's some cloud service that we can use to do this. Azure and Amazon offer cloud DB storage, I guess we can use them, but that means a lot of setup work as well. Not sure if there's a 3rd party email analytics in the cloud service.

Any recommendations on best way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, tracking your email links and analyzing the relevant is a lot of work. I recomend you use a third party application to take care of it.

Most email-as-a-service providers offer prety goood analytics, including things like opens, clicks, by location, time, etc...

It really depends on the provider, but I think you should take a look at some of the best known ones such as [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com), [Postmarkapp](http://postmarkapp.com) or [Mailjet](http://mailjet.com)